# What is this syntax? myVariable!=null?myVariable:5

Tags: java

Hello guys very simple question for you.
I just dont know how to google this, we use this in our framework and i want learn more about it but i dont know what is it.  can you please help?This is simplest example.Any lead how can i google it will be good answer for me.

```
 myVariable != null ? myVariable : 5
```

Comment: ternary operator

Comment: That is a conditional `?:` expression, sometimes imprecisely called the ternary expression (it _is_ a ternary expression, but it's just 1 kind of ternary expression). It's described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html ("Another conditional operator is `?:`")

Comment: It reads a bit easier if you add spaces and parenthesis: `(myVariable != null) ? myVariable : 5`

Comment: There's several bits of syntax going on, so which part are you asking about? Because this code looks incomplete: it doesn't "result" in anything, even if it does something on its own (it will evaluate a ternary, and the result will be uselessly thrown away in the code you're showing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ternary operator. If `myVariable` does not equal `null`, the expression evaluates to `myVariable`. Otherwise, `5`*.

Equivalent to:

```
myVariable == null ? 5 : myVariable
```

*Since `myVariable` is compared to `null`, this is clearly an object rather than a primitive, so the entire expression is expected to return an object, so technically this returns `Integer.valueOf(5)`.